# Size discrepancy in file deflated using zlib and Crypto++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, zlib, crypto++

I'm learning how to raw deflate (no header or trailer information) & inflate data in C++, so I decided to try the `zlib` and `Crypto++` libraries.
I've found that, when deflating the same file, `Crypto++` sometimes adds 4 extra bytes (depending on the method used).

For example, for a file containing the following sequence, whitespaces included: `1 2 3 4 5 6`, deflating with `zlib` produces a file of size 14 bytes.

This holds true for `Crypto++ deflate_method1`, but for `Crypto++ deflate_method2`, the file size is 18 bytes.

Also, when trying to inflate a file that was deflated using `Crypto++ deflate_method2` with `Crypto++ inflate_method1`, an exception is raised:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::Inflator::UnexpectedEndErr'
  what():  Inflator: unexpected end of compressed block
Aborted (core dumped)
```

To compare, I did another test deflating/inflating with Python:

- Deflating also yields a file of size 14 bytes.
- I'm able to inflate all the deflated files correctly, regardless of the method used to deflate them.

At this point, I would like to understand two things:

1. Why is there a discrepancy in the size of the deflated files?
2. Why Python is able to inflate any of the files but Crypto++ is being picky?

---

### Info & code:

- **OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
- **Zlib version:** 1.0.1 from Ubuntu repos.
- **Crypto++ version:** 8.0.2 from GitHub release.
- **Python version:** 3.5.2

  - **zlib version:** 1.2.8 / **runtime version:** 1.2.8

**Input & output files as base64:**

- Input: `MSAyIDMgNCA1IDYK`
- Deflated:

  - Python: `M1QwUjBWMFEwVTDjAgA=`
  - Zlib: `M1QwUjBWMFEwVTDjAgA=`
  - Crypto++ method1: `M1QwUjBWMFEwVTDjAgA=`
  - Crypto++ method2: `MlQwUjBWMFEwVTDjAgAAAP//`

**Zlib:**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "zlib.h"

constexpr uint32_t BUFFER_READ_SIZE  = 128;
constexpr uint32_t BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE = 128;

bool mydeflate(std::vector<unsigned char> & input)
{
    const std::string inputStream{ input.begin(), input.end() };
    uint64_t inputSize = input.size();

    // Create a string stream where output will be created.
    std::stringstream outputStringStream(std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    // Initialize zlib structures.
    std::vector<char *> readBuffer(BUFFER_READ_SIZE);
    std::vector<char *> writeBuffer(BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE);

    z_stream zipStream;
    zipStream.avail_in = 0;
    zipStream.avail_out = BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE;
    zipStream.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(writeBuffer.data());
    zipStream.total_in = 0;
    zipStream.total_out = 0;
    zipStream.data_type = Z_BINARY;
    zipStream.zalloc = nullptr;
    zipStream.zfree =  nullptr;
    zipStream.opaque = nullptr;

    // Window bits is passed < 0 to tell that there is no zlib header.
    if (deflateInit2_(&zipStream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, -MAX_WBITS, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY, ZLIB_VERSION, sizeof(zipStream)) != Z_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Deflate the input stream
    uint32_t readSize = 0;
    uint64_t dataPendingToCompress = inputSize;
    uint64_t dataPendingToWrite = 0;
    bool     isEndOfInput = false;

    while (dataPendingToCompress > 0)
    {
        if (dataPendingToCompress > BUFFER_READ_SIZE)
        {
            readSize = BUFFER_READ_SIZE;
        }
        else
        {
            readSize = dataPendingToCompress;
            isEndOfInput = true;
        }

        // Copy the piece of input stream to the read buffer.
        std::memcpy(readBuffer.data(), &inputStream[inputSize - dataPendingToCompress], readSize);
        dataPendingToCompress -= readSize;

        zipStream.next_in = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(readBuffer.data());
        zipStream.avail_in = readSize;

        // While there is input data to compress.
        while (zipStream.avail_in > 0)
        {
            // Output buffer is full.
            if (zipStream.avail_out == 0)
            {
                outputStringStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(writeBuffer.data()), dataPendingToWrite);

                zipStream.total_in = 0;
                zipStream.avail_out = BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE;
                zipStream.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(writeBuffer.data());
                dataPendingToWrite = 0;
            }

            uint64_t totalOutBefore = zipStream.total_out;

            int zlibError = deflate(&zipStream, isEndOfInput ? Z_FINISH : Z_NO_FLUSH);

            if ((zlibError != Z_OK) && (zlibError != Z_STREAM_END))
            {
                deflateEnd(&zipStream);

                return false;
            }

            dataPendingToWrite += static_cast<uint64_t>(zipStream.total_out - totalOutBefore);
        }
    }

    // Flush last compressed data.
    while (dataPendingToWrite > 0)
    {
        if (dataPendingToWrite > BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE)
        {
            outputStringStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(writeBuffer.data()), BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE);
        }
        else
        {
            outputStringStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(writeBuffer.data()), dataPendingToWrite);
        }

        zipStream.total_in = 0;
        zipStream.avail_out = BUFFER_WRITE_SIZE;
        zipStream.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef *>(writeBuffer.data());

        uint64_t totalOutBefore = zipStream.total_out;
        int zlibError = deflate(&zipStream, Z_FINISH);

        if ((zlibError != Z_OK) && (zlibError != Z_STREAM_END))
        {
            deflateEnd(&zipStream);

            return false;
        }

        dataPendingToWrite = static_cast<uint64_t>(zipStream.total_out - totalOutBefore);
    }

    deflateEnd(&zipStream);

    const std::string & outputString = outputStringStream.str();
    std::vector<unsigned char> deflated{outputString.begin(), outputString.end()};
    
    std::cout << "Output String size: " << outputString.size() << std::endl;

    input.swap(deflated);

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input_file{"/tmp/test.txt"};
    std::vector<unsigned char> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    std::cout << "Deflated: " << mydeflate(data) << '\n';
    
    std::ofstream output_file{"/tmp/deflated.txt"};
    output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data.data()), data.size());
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Crypto++:**

```
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/zdeflate.h"
#include "cryptopp/zinflate.h"

void deflate_method1(const std::string & input_file_path, const std::string & output_file_path)
{
    CryptoPP::Deflator deflator(new CryptoPP::FileSink(output_file_path.c_str(), true), CryptoPP::Deflator::DEFAULT_DEFLATE_LEVEL, CryptoPP::Deflator::MAX_LOG2_WINDOW_SIZE);
    CryptoPP::FileSource fs(input_file_path.c_str(), true);
    fs.TransferAllTo(deflator);
}

void inflate_method1(const std::string & input_file_path, const std::string & output_file_path)
{
    CryptoPP::FileSource fs(input_file_path.c_str(), true);
    CryptoPP::Inflator inflator(new CryptoPP::FileSink(output_file_path.c_str(), true));
    fs.TransferAllTo(inflator);
}

void deflate_method2(const std::string& input_file_path, const std::string& output_file_path)
{
  CryptoPP::Deflator deflator(new CryptoPP::FileSink(output_file_path.c_str(), true), CryptoPP::Deflator::DEFAULT_DEFLATE_LEVEL, 15);

  std::ifstream file_in;
  file_in.open(input_file_path, std::ios::binary);

  std::string buffer;
  size_t num_read = 0;

  const size_t buffer_size(1024 * 1024);
  buffer.resize(buffer_size);
  file_in.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer_size);
  num_read = file_in.gcount();

  while (num_read) {
    deflator.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char *>(buffer.data())), num_read);
    file_in.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer_size);
    num_read = file_in.gcount();
  }

  file_in.close();
  deflator.Flush(true);
}

void inflate_method2(const std::string& input_file_path, const std::string& output_file_path)
{
  CryptoPP::Inflator inflator(new CryptoPP::FileSink(output_file_path.c_str(), true));

  std::ifstream file_in;
  file_in.open(input_file_path, std::ios::binary);

  std::string buffer;
  size_t num_read = 0;

  const size_t buffer_size(1024 * 1024);
  buffer.resize(buffer_size);
  file_in.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer_size);
  num_read = file_in.gcount();

  while (num_read) {
    inflator.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char *>(buffer.data())), num_read);
    file_in.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer_size);
    num_read = file_in.gcount();
  }

  file_in.close();
  inflator.Flush(true);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    deflate_method1("/tmp/test.txt", "/tmp/deflated_method1.bin");
    inflate_method1("/tmp/deflated_method1.bin", "/tmp/inflated_method1.txt");

    deflate_method2("/tmp/test.txt", "/tmp/deflated_method2.bin");
    inflate_method2("/tmp/deflated_method2.bin", "/tmp/inflated_method2.txt");
    // This throws:    Inflator: unexpected end of compressed block 
    inflate_method1("/tmp/deflated_method2.bin", "/tmp/inflated_with_method1_file_deflated_with_method2.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

**Python:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import zlib


def CHUNKSIZE():
    return 128


def deflate(file_path, compression_level, method, wbits):
    plain_data = None
    deflated_data = bytearray()
    deflator = zlib.compressobj(compression_level, method, wbits)

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as input_file:
            while True:
                plain_data = input_file.read(CHUNKSIZE())

                if not plain_data:
                    break

                deflated_data += deflator.compress(plain_data)

    deflated_data += deflator.flush()

    return deflated_data


def inflate(file_path, wbits):
    inflated_data = bytearray()
    inflator = zlib.decompressobj(wbits)

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as deflated_file:
        buffer = deflated_file.read(CHUNKSIZE())

        while buffer:
            inflated_data += inflator.decompress(buffer)
            buffer = deflated_file.read(CHUNKSIZE())

        inflated_data += inflator.flush()

    return inflated_data


def write_file(file_path, data):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    deflated_data = deflate("/tmp/test.txt", zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    write_file("/tmp/deflated_python.bin", deflated_data)
```

Comment: Doing it by hand with all the buffers and paddings, it's just error prone. `zlib.h` offers simple `compress2` and `uncompress` functions, which do everything in one call. I know this doesn't solve your problem; That extra data probably comes from garbage left in some buffer, that should have been cut, but was read anyways during the last chunk or so. Happened to me too.

Comment: For what I'm seeing, `compress2` it's not raw deflate, as it adds header and trailer information. Still, a nice function to have.

Comment: Also it seems that it's not suitable for huge files, as all the content would need to be passed in one go.

Comment: You should compile and run code that you intend to post, before you post it.

Comment: What, _exactly_ is your input? I get eight bytes out for "123456", 13 bytes out for "1 2 3 4 5 6" (with interspersed spaces, implied but not stated in your question).

Comment: Please put the 14-byte and 18-byte deflated outputs in your question. In either hex or base-64.

Comment: @MarkAdler I fixed the code and posted the input & output as base-64 as requested. The input is including whitespaces, so "1 2 3 4 5 6". In my system I'm getting 14 bytes. I also clarified this in the original post. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: In the Crypto++ version you open the file with `std::ios::binary` while in the zlib version you don't. Could change everything, could change nothing at all.

Comment: Still not stating your input correctly. From your base64, your input is actually "1 2 3 4 5 6\n". _Now_ it gives 14 bytes compressed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was a newline. When I open the file in Vim I only see the line with the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three are working correctly, generating a valid deflate compressed stream with a single, last deflate block.

You "Crypto++ method2" is generating two deflate blocks, where the second one is an empty stored block that is not marked as the last block. This is not a valid deflate stream since it does not terminate. You are not correctly finishing the compression.

Your `deflator.Flush(true)` is flushing the first block and emitting that empty stored block, without ending the deflate stream.

I'm not seeing much in the way of documentation, or really any at all, but looking at the source code, I would try `deflator.EndBlock(true)` instead.

*Update:*

Per the comment below, `EndBlock` is not public. Instead `MessageEnd` is what is needed to terminate the deflate stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of the empty block. Just a little comment: the `EndBlock` method is protected and cannot be accessed, but the `MessageEnd` is public and generates the same deflated file as `method1`.

Comment: Another thing: do you know why Python is inflating the file without complaining when the deflate stream is invalid?

Comment: @AdriC.S. You should post an answer to your own question with the corrected code.

Comment: Python _is_ complaining. You're just not listening. You need to check `inflator.eof` to see if the stream terminated properly. Python decompressed what you provided just fine, but it was left waiting for more.